# Power BI: Max value of all children

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a dim table with hierarchy as

| ID | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B | A |
| C | B |
| D | B |
| E | A |

A is the top level, while B and E are its children, C, D are the grandchildren.

Then I have a fact table

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |
| E | 5 |

And I would like to have a 3rd column contains the max value of its all children, as

| ID | Value | maxV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 5 |
| B | 2 | 4 |
| C | 3 | 3 |
| D | 4 | 3 |
| E | 5 | 5 |

For all the lowest level children, the max value equals itself.  For the parent, for example B, the max value is 4 since its child C's value is 3, and D is 4, and 2 for itself. Max(2, 3, 4) = 4, same as for A, it equals Max(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) = 5.

Can such thing be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, firstly you'll need to figure out how to get a total list of parent/child relationships all the way down the hierarchy. You can use PATH for that, see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/understanding-functions-for-parent-child-hierarchies-in-dax).

```
Path = PATH(Table1[ID], Table1[Parent])
```

Then, you can look up the value for each ID of that Path by creating a little temp table with one row for each item in the Path (for this row), look up the value, then concatenate all those values together back into a Path-esque list.
(optional, but good to visualize what you're doing).

```
PathVals = VAR temp =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [Path] ) ),
            "MyID", PATHITEM ( [Path], [Value] )
        ),
        "Val", LOOKUPVALUE ( Table2[Value], [ID], [MyID] )
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX ( temp, [Val], "|", [Value], ASC )
```

Finally, instead of doing that last `CONCATENATEX` step, you can instead just get the max value of whatever is in the temp table.

```
PathMAX = VAR temp =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [Path] ) ),
            "MyID", PATHITEM ( [Path], [Value] )
        ),
        "Val", LOOKUPVALUE ( Table2[Value], [ID], [MyID] )
    )
RETURN
    MaXX(temp, [Val])
```

Done. :)

[image: the visual outputs]